# Show FastScroll only if the list data is enough to be scrolled

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` and i need to turn the visibility of `FastScroll` always enabled. The issue is, when the **list items** are only a few (say only 2 or 3) and easily to be fitted on screen, obviously they can't be scrolled. But the `FastScroll` is still on screen i.e visible. How can i disable it or hide it when the **list items** are fewer than to be scrollable.

[image]

Comment: Show your code where you enable fast scroll

Comment: M enabling the fast_scroll in my listview.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable/disable the fast scroll feature programmatically via the [`setFastScrollEnabled(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled%28boolean%29) method.

So just check how many entries your list has, and enable/disable fast scroll accordingly.

Comment: But how can do i know, that i have enough items to be shown on screen that can't be scrolled. coz devices' sizes changes device to device.

Comment: Fast scroll should only be enabled if you really have _a lot_ of items. For a normal amount of items (say up to 20 or 30 or so) the normal scrolling behaviour of a listview should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Don't listen to @Ridcully. Default behavior is rarely optimal and this isn't too hard to do. The following method does require that you know your item height. This also has your activity implement OnPreDrawListener.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    itemViewHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_height);

    adapter = new YourAdapterClass();
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = list.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (vto != null && list.getMeasuredHeight() == 0) {
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(this);
    } else if (list.getMeasuredHeight() != 0) {
        listViewHeight = list.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}

public void setData(Object data) {
    // Set your adapter data how ever you do.
    adapter.setData(data);
    handleFastScrollVisibility();
}

private void handleFastScrollVisibility() {
    if (listViewHeight == 0 || list == null) return;

    int itemCount = adapter.getCount();
    int totalItemHeight = itemCount * itemViewHeight;

    list.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(totalItemHeight > listViewHeight);
}

@Override
public boolean onPreDraw() {
    ViewTreeObserver vto = list.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (vto != null) vto.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

    listViewHeight = list.getMeasuredHeight();
    handleFastScrollVisibility();

    return true;
}
```

Basicly you don't know when the height of the ListView is going to be ready. That's why you add a predraw listener, it will notify you when it is ready. I don't know how you get your data but this method assumes that you don't know if your ListView height or your data will be ready first. How you add data to your adapter will be depend on your adapter.